# Why emacs tab-completion does not split window

Tags: emacs, tab-completion

Run emacs without X support. `M-x shell` to open shell.

after i cd to a directory which contains to sub directories, namely "dirA", "dirB"

then i type "ls dir" and then press Tab to complete

emacs does not split the current window into two windows and show the *Completions* buffer below the shell buffer. it shows the *Completions* just in the window that originally shows the shell, and the shell disappeared.

how can the *completion* automatically split the shell window and display below the shell, instead of replacing the shell window?

Comment: Cannot reproduce here.  Try with "emacs -Q" to isolate misconfiguration in your init file.

Comment: i installed emacs on a server that has no x11. In the configure process, it report an error "you seem to be running x, but no x development libraries found", and i follow it's advice to configure with "--without-x" option. that leads to this result.

Comment: I'd be a bit surprised if building Emacs `--without-x` was any different to building with X, but running with `-nw` (in this respect, at least). Which platform and version of Emacs? More importantly, it's not clear whether you've actually followed huaiyuan's suggestion. Do you still have this issue when running `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: many thanks to huaiyuan and phils, I tried -Q option and it works well now.